What is the difference between ‘coming to Jesus’ and ‘believing in Jesus’ in John 6:35
John 6:34-36 (NKJV)

Then they said to Him, “Lord, give us this bread always.”
And Jesus said to them, “I am the bread of life. He who comes to Me shall never hunger, and he who believes in Me shall never
thirst. But I said to you that you have seen Me and yet do not
believe.

In what way does Jesus differentiate between the act of ‘coming to Him’ and the act of ‘believing in Him’?
What is the significance of this distinction in the context of the passage?

In those times they were very eloquent. I suppose Jesus is using here an isocolon - a rhetoric figure where two sentences that are structurally the same (i.e parallel structure).

Jesus is making a distinction here between 'coming' 'seeing' and believing'. There is no 'parallelism'. That idea just obscures the distinction that Jesus is making. This is a common way of trivialising the words of Jesus, and avoiding the truth of what he speaks.

I am not sure that Jesus is making a distinction between "coming" and "believing".  Indeed, the statement in John 6:35 appears to be quintessential Hebrew synthetic parallelism:

And Jesus said: I am the bread of life:

He who comes to Me shall never hunger,
and he who believes in Me shall never thirst.

But I said to you that you have seen Me and yet do not believe.

Note that "believe" and "come" are parallel; just as are "hunger" and "thirst".
There is a similar set of quadruple parallelisms in V53-56 showing the equivalence of eating and drinking Jesus' spiritual food/drink:

So Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I tell you,

unless you eat the flesh and drink the blood of the Son of Man, you have no life in you.
Whoever eats My flesh and drinks My blood has eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day.
For My flesh is real food, and My blood is real drink.
Whoever eats My flesh and drinks My blood remains in Me, and I in him.



In the text quoted, 5,000 had followed Jesus over land and sea, to get to him in a remote region. The reason for such determined following? "Because they saw his miracles which he did on them that were diseased." (John 6:2 A.V.) That was why they came to Jesus, on that grassy mountain-side. They came in their thousands. They came to be witnesses to more miracles. And Jesus did not disappoint. He fed all of them with just 5 barley-loaves and 2 small fish.
This demonstrates how it is possible to come to Jesus with wrong motives. It wasn't that their expectations of Jesus were wrong - he did what they'd hoped (expected) him to do for them - a miracle. But they were seeking personal benefits, and a free lunch on epic scale no doubt thrilled them. That has remained the case for well nigh 2,000 years, although many others have come in faith to Jesus, believing him to be who he claims to be. They have come despite knowing their unworthiness to be granted the least of his favours. They come, just as they are, confessing their sin and seeking to be restored to a broken relationship with God through what Jesus did at Golgotha. Their belief in Jesus differs from initial belief many others had but which did not amount to saving faith.
Those 5,000 did not have saving faith in Jesus, despite coming to him, despite witnessing yet another miracle that blessed them. The rest of John chapter 6 expands on the meaning of the text in question.
From verse 59 to 69 we learn that many of his disciples who heard his preaching in the synagogue at Capernaum began to turn away from Jesus due to his teaching. They began to murmur against it, and Jesus knew their unbelieving thoughts, and who had them (verses 61-62 & 68). Therefore, "from that time on, many of his disciples went back, and walked no more with him" (verse 67).
This clearly shows that, despite having come to Jesus and becoming his disciples, they had not believed in Jesus in the way that those who will be with Christ eternally believe.
This distinction in John's gospel (continuing to the end of that chapter) is immensely important. The Father has to draw individuals to Christ and, without any contradiction, only Christ can lead people to the Father (verses 37, 44, & see also John 14:6). Anyone who thinks it's up to them to decide to come to Jesus and that 'believing in Jesus' means believing their decision will turn what they see as only 'a possibility of salvation' until they make that decision, into granted salvation, is no different to those 5,000 (and his disciples in that synagogue), happy to follow Jesus for personal perks, but balking at his hard teachings.
The critical difference is that, after coming to Jesus, then belief in who he really is, what he really achieved at Golgotha and his resurrection, turns into saving faith in him. And that kind of faith is a free gift from God, who knows their hearts - Ephesians 2:8 & Romans 3:27-28 & 9:30-33.
SUMMARY SENTENCE:  Anyone coming to Jesus because the Father has drawn them, will never be turned away by Jesus, but be enabled to believe in him in the way the scriptures state as to who he really is and what he has really done.

Up-voted +1. Excellent answer.

UV. I agree with Dottard that there seems to be parallelism, but I believe that your exegesis on the distinction is solid!

The concept of "believing in Jesus" is generally well understood and not particularly controversial. However, the notion of "coming to Jesus" would require further examination.
Earlier in the context, the crowd that witnessed the Miracle of Feeding the 5000 sought out Jesus and found Him in Capernaum. Their act of "coming to Jesus" did not impress Him, as they were seeking physical sustenance rather than spiritual fulfillment. This is evident in the dialogue between the crowd and Jesus in John 6:26-29

26 Jesus answered, “Very truly I tell you, you are looking for me, not because you saw the signs I performed but because you ate the loaves and had your fill. 27 Do not work for food that spoils, but for food that endures to eternal life, which the Son of Man will give you. For on him God the Father has placed his seal of approval.” 28 Then they asked him, “What must we do to do the works God requires?” 29 Jesus answered, “The work of God is this: to believe in the one he has sent.”

Despite having witnessed the miracle, The crowd failed to recognize Jesus is the one and asked for another sign. This is further illustrated in John 6:30-34. Continue to John 6:35-37 NIV;

35 Then Jesus declared, “I am the bread of life. Whoever comes to me will never go hungry, and whoever believes in me will never be thirsty. 36 But as I told you, you have seen me and still you do not believe. 37 All those the Father gives me will come to me, and whoever comes to me I will never drive away.

The act of "coming to Jesus" might be misunderstood as a personal initiative. However, as Jesus clarifies in John 6:37, those who come to Him are chosen by the Father. Clearly, those who are chosen possess an unwavering faith in Jesus.
Therefore in Jesus' expression, there is no distinction between "coming" to Him and "believing" in Him.

Although in Greek here, this matches synonymous poetic Hebrew form.  Thus, in the sense of Jesus' meaning here, he who comes equals he who believes and hunger equals thirst.
     ὁ ἐρχόμενος    πρὸς    ἐμὲ     οὐ μὴ   πεινάσῃ , 
καὶ  ὁ πιστεύων     εἰς     ἐμὲ     οὐ μὴ   διψήσει    πώποτε. 

How these words fit into the context is interesting.  They came to Jesus for the wrong reason.  They saw physically, but they did not see/understand.

Truly, truly, I say to you, you are seeking me, not because you saw signs, but because you ate your fill of the loaves.
(John 6:26, ESV2016)

Their mindset is completely different than what Jesus was saying:

Do not work for the food that perishes, but for the food that endures to eternal life, which the Son of Man will give to you.
(John 6:27, ESV2016)


Then they said to him, “What must we do, to be doing the works of God?”  Jesus answered them, “This is the work of God, that you believe in him whom he has sent.”
(John 6:28–29, ESV2016)

They faced Jesus with the same temptations he had faced to sidetrack his ministry after his baptism.  To give them bread alone:

Our fathers ate the manna in the wilderness; as it is written, ‘He gave them bread from heaven to eat.’ ”
(John 6:31, ESV2016)


They said to him, “Sir, give us this bread always.”
(John 6:34, ESV2016)

To base faith on sight exclusively through signs:

So they said to him, “Then what sign do you do, that we may see and believe you? What work do you perform?
(John 6:30, 2016)

To establish an earthly world government:

Perceiving then that they were about to come and take him by force to make him king, Jesus withdrew again to the mountain by himself.
(John 6:15, ESV2026)

Essentially, they did not believe what Jesus was telling them because they came to Jesus for the wrong reasons/motives.  Their minds were stuck on the physical and did not see the spiritual.

But I said to you that you have seen me and yet do not believe.
(John 6:36, ESV2016)

But some of his disciples began to understand:

After this many of his disciples turned back and no longer walked with him.  So Jesus said to the twelve, “Do you want to go away as well?”  Simon Peter answered him, “Lord, to whom shall we go? You have the words of eternal life, and we have believed, and have come to know, that you are the Holy One of God.”
(John 6:66–69, ESV2016)

Thus, when we understand what Jesus said in v35, come and believe represent the same thing.

UV. That was a very nice break down. I appreciate that you took the time to look at it verse by verse.
